# PHP and Mysql query does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a web application and I would like to search in a mysql database with a php script.
But my code does not work as expected.
Here is my code:

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$sql_cautare="SELECT * FROM carti WHERE titlu = "$search"";
```

I have search form..and I want to select those values that are entered in the search form.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM carti WHERE titlu = '$search'";`

Comment: So ..I should not use double quotes..right?

Comment: Yes because that would terminate the string.

Comment: You should use prepared statements instead of injecting user input into queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: There must be other errors too because it still does not work.

Comment: excape the double quotes.

Comment: Can you explain what **exactly** is not working? Is there any error message given?

Comment: You cannot use unescaped double-quotes in a double-quoted string. And you should not execute user input as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql_cautare = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM carti WHERE titlu = ?");
$sql_cautare->bind_param('s', $search);
$sql_cautare->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
 $sql_cautare = "SELECT * FROM carti WHERE titlu = '$search'";
```

But you should definitly do some input sanitization before using it in SQL!

Comment: No, nowadays, one should use prepared statements